# PHP recursively traverse object tree

Tags: php, recursion

I have got a $branch object that can contain other $branch objects:

```
$branch->children();
```

Each of them can have $apples as children.

```
$branch->apples();
```

How can I collect all of the $apples from the $branch recursively?

```
function collectApples($branch){
    $apples = array();
    ?
    return $apples;
}
```

Comment: Look for 'textbook'-examples on how to traverse trees.

Comment: Is $brach and Object? how do i get the other Branches and how do I get the Apples?

Comment: Look into PHP's SPL iterators and array_merge_recursive.

Comment: Tree Traversal -> [`RecursiveIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIterator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collects all the apples of a specific branch using a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search):

```
function collectApples($branch) {
    $apples = $branch->apples();
    foreach ($branch->children() as $child) {
        $apples = array_merge($apples, collectApples($child));
    }
    return $apples;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$child->apples()` be changed to `collectApples($child)` to make this work recursivley?

Answer (score 1):

```
function collectApples($branch) {
    $apples = $branch->apples();
    foreach ($branch->children() as $child) 
        $apples = array_merge($apples, collectApples($child));
    return $apples;
}
```

@TimCooper's answer <strike>will only fetch you first generation children while this slight modification on his answer</strike> will get you the apples for all children and the children of children (based on my reading of the question this is what I understood you were needing).

You can check a sample here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9dk-zjc

**EDIT NOTE:** At the time this answer was written @TimCooper's answer was not complete - now as it stands they are identical.

Comment: That's exactly the same code as mine, no?

Comment: @TimCooper It wasn't when I began work on the question - now that you've corrected your's however. Unfortunately edits don't alert you when you're writing an answer. To clarify my answer has been updated to reflect the incident.